# Is this pgRouting perfomance acceptable for my tiny server?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I'm testing pgrouting functions in a tiny server with 2GB of RAM and a dual core processor. 
I wrote a program that create client process and they connect to the server in a specific hour to perform a query, in fact the query is a pgrouting function call. My trouble is that after 50 process, the server crash and report this error in the postgres log:

> terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>   2012-09-05 15:59:09 VET DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this
>   server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
>   another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
>   memory. 2012-09-05 15:59:09 VET HINT:  In a moment you should be able
>   to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.

and this error occurs for every process.

The table that contains the graph information has about 300,000 rows. The graph has 250 nodes aprox.

My question: is it ok that this behavior occurs with a server like this and using a table with this amount of rows?

Comment: Adding the SQL queries you use to the question could be helpful, since maybe someone can optimise them.

Comment: I tried with a query like this:

Comment: I tried with a query like this: 

select shortest_path_astar('select id, source, target, cost2 as cost, x1, y1, x2, y2,  reverse_cost2 as reverse_cost from graph_streets', 15478, 56874, true, true);

The testing program was written in python using  psycopg2. I tried with threads and process.